# Calculate MACD using postgres

Tags: postgresql, stock, moving-average, timescaledb

I am trying to calculate the MACD of BTC. I have a materialized view/continuous aggregate like this:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS candle_1_minute
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT time_bucket('1 minute', time) as bucket,
       product_id,
       MAX(price) as high,
       MIN(price) as low,
       FIRST(price, time) as open,
       LAST(price, time) as close
FROM ticker
GROUP BY 2, 1
ORDER BY 1, 2
WITH NO DATA;
```

I create the exponential moving average like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ema_func(previous numeric, close numeric, observations numeric)
  returns numeric
  language plpgsql as
$$
begin
  raise info 'previous %, close %', $1, $2;
  return case
         when previous is null then close
         else (close * (2/observations+1)) + (previous * (1-(2/observations+1)))
         end;
end
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE ema(numeric, numeric) (sfunc = ema_func, stype = numeric);
```

I create the MACD from the continuous aggregate/materialized view:

```sql
SELECT
    sub.bucket as time,
    sub.macd,
    ema(sub.macd, 9) over(ORDER BY sub.bucket rows between 8 preceding and current row) AS signal
FROM (
    SELECT
        bucket,
        product_id,
        ema(close, 12) OVER(ORDER BY bucket ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) - ema(close, 26) OVER(ORDER BY bucket ROWS BETWEEN 25 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS macd
    FROM candle_1_minute
    WHERE product_id = 'BTC-GBP'
    ORDER BY bucket
) sub
ORDER BY bucket;
```

I create the histogram like this:

```sql
SELECT
    sub.bucket as time,
    sub.macd - ema(sub.macd, 9) over(ORDER BY sub.bucket rows between 8 preceding and current row) as hist
FROM (
    SELECT
        bucket,
        close,
        ema(close, 12) OVER(ORDER BY bucket ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) - ema(close, 26) OVER(ORDER BY bucket ROWS BETWEEN 25 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS macd
    FROM candle_1_minute
    WHERE product_id = 'BTC-GBP'
    ORDER BY bucket
) sub
ORDER BY bucket;
```

But neither the graphed histogram or the macd graph resemble that of https://cryptowat.ch/charts/COINBASE-PRO:BTC-GBP (as an example)

[image: histogram-and-macd]

Here is some sample data used to generate the graph (timebucket, high,low,open,close).
https://zerobin.net/?612a684f982f1efb#JeB5wKWKqIFGQUFpy0vQPXlR02GYK7KbMZaXsPl/tls=

Is my query to create the macd and signal lines incorrect? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you figured out this issue since posting this?

Comment: No. I changed my approach and used Pandas for this part instead.

Comment: I recently found this post https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-calculate-technical-indicators-in-bigquery-using-sql-moving-averages-rsi-macd-b58b16e4f52e, but I'm going with a library instead as well